# Can I perform Prayer (Salah) at home without looking the jammath in the masjid?

Tags: salat, jamaat

While I am at home can I pray Salah at home when the jammat timing is not over. And also I can't reach the Mosque on time to attend the jammat.

So is there any problem if I pray alone at home?

Comment: what do you mean when you say jammath?

Comment: If you are asking about if you MUST pray in the mosque gathered with others then I could respond to that.  3 out of the 4 madhahib states that it's not fard or wajib  (obligatory) to pray in the masjid. only the hanbali madhab sees it as obligatory.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your significant question that asked:

> can i pray namaz alone in the home without looking the jammath in the
>   masjid

According to the narrations of both Sunni and Shia, it is quoted that:

> Namaz (salah) al-Jamma’a is considered as a Sunna of Prophet Muhammad
>   (pbuh) and it is said nobody will reach the actual Salah if s/he
>   leaves it without any excuse (persuasive excuse).

Accordingly, it demonstrates the significance of salah al-Jamma’a, but it shows that it would be accepted if you have excuse (persuasive excuse).

---

**Reference(s):**

- [wikifeqh.ir](http://wikifeqh.ir/%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B2_%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA)
- Sonan Ibn majed, V.1, P.255/260
- Usul Kafi, V.3, P.372

Comment: I Thank you for your answers, they have ALWAYS references. "... If you have excuse." means that if you don't have any excuse then you can't pray alone. But it's not true!

Comment: Nice pointed dear HOPE.  Perhpas it would indicates its importance that how much it is important..., although your Salah would be accepted even if you do it solely, but with less rewards ... Well done for pondering dear good curious mate.

Answer (score 1):

Praying in jamaa’ah (congregation) in the mosque is one of the most important rituals of Islam, and it is obligatory for every man past the age of adolescence who is able to hear the call to prayer, because of a great deal of evidence, including the words of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him):

> “Whoever hears the call to prayer and does not respond, his prayer is
>   not valid, except the one who has an excuse.”

Narrated by Ibn Maajah, 793; also narrated by al-Daaraqutni and al-Haakim, who classed it as saheeh. It was also classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Ibn Maajah.

> Muslim narrated (653) that Abu Hurayrah said: A blind man came to the
>   Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and said, “O
>   Messenger of Allaah, I do not have anyone to lead me to the mosque,”
>   and he asked the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be
>   upon him) to grant him a concession allowing him to pray in his house.
>   He granted him that concession, then when he turned to leave he called
>   him back and said, “Can you hear the call to prayer?” He said, “Yes.”
>   He said, ‘Then answer it.”

So, if you live at such a distance from the masjid (mosque), from which on a quiet day, you can hear the adhaan, then you are obliged to pray with the jamaah in the masjid. Unless however if you missed the jamaah for some valid excuse, such as you were very hungry and your wife served you food just as the adhaan was being said, then you can eat first as is authentically narrated, or its very bad weather, or you have a contagious illness.

So basically, you are obliged under normal conditions if you live within a certain distance of the masjid, unless you are excused for some reason.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

Without valid excuse, you shouldn't forsake praying in a jama'at, even if it is a jamaa't comprising two men.

Even in worse condition, our prophet went to mosque for praying in jama'at.

Comment: Did You always pray in jamaat?!? that answer like this!! Then Please include references not your own idea.